# SVN delete file issue on the server

Tags: svn

I'm having issue with SVN. All of a sudden I cannot delete the file on my server.

the directory shows the following and the path of the folder is as follows

```
dev:/usr/HTTPServer/htdocs/en_US/sc/us/en$

drwxrwxr-x    3 277      1               512 Jan 16 11:49 readynow/
-rw-rw-r--    1 304      1             14812 Jan 11 11:19 readynow
```

I want to delete the readynow without the slash.

```
dev:/usr/HTTPServer/htdocs/en_US/sc$ svn revert readynow
svn: Cannot revert: 'readynow' is not under version control
```

svn status shows me this... msg and I don't seem to understand the (A + sign) and why can't I delete that readynow

```
dev:/usr/HTTPServer/htdocs/en_US/sc$ svn st
D      index-not-minified.html
A  +   readynow
```

When I run the st and then run svn ci -m "delete" it throws the following error.

Deleting       us/en/index-not-minified.html 
Adding         us/en/readynow

```
dev:/usr/HTTPServer/htdocs/en_US/sc$ svn st
svn: Commit failed (details follow):
svn: MERGE request failed on '/svn-sc/us/en'
svn: 
Invalid changes line in rev-file
```

Answer (score 0):

1 Don't ask 3 unrelated questions in single post
2 Read docs! `svn help status` will show you **clearly**, why you can't (using svn) delete readynow, and `svn help revert` will show also, that you tried **wrong command** for deleting files (when this file **is** version-controlled)

`A  +   readynow`, according to help, means:

> First column: Says if item was added, deleted, or otherwise changed
>
> ...
>
> ```
>  'A' Added
> ```
>
> Fourth column: Scheduled commit will contain addition-with-history
>
> ...
>
> ```
>  '+' history scheduled with commit
> ```

I.e - readynow currently is not under version control, will appear in repo only after commit, this object has previous history in repository (exist early???), which will be added to repo with the file

3 For "MERGE request failed on" problem

This seems to be a [known](http://svn.haxx.se/users/archive-2006-06/1164.shtml) [problem](https://ssl.supermind.nl/collab/projects/submin/ticket/269) most likely caused by a faulty post-commit hook

4 For "Invalid changes line in rev-file" nothing definitive exist, except of mentions of possible problems with FSFS (long versions ago - 2004 and [2007 years](http://subversion.open.collab.net/ds/viewMessage.do?dsForumId=4&dsMessageId=1153)) and giant transaction

because you wrote nothing about your OS, version of SVN, type of repo, repo size... I can't say more - only "verify repository, create and use new WC".

Comment: The first 2 code blocks are showing you my server structure and that the folder I was trying to add is not under version control. Secondly, the 2nd code block is giving me an error when I am trying to revert the file. When I did the svn st it gave me that the msg with A + and later when I tried to commit the addition it gave me that error, so I don't understand why you think I've asked 3 separate questions. It's one question on how do I delete the file which is not in version control and is giving me the following error msgs when I try to delete and commit.

Comment: @Vish - remove file from local FS is always `rm <FILE>`

Comment: I know of that command to remove files but even after I do svn rm <file> and them do svn ci -m "remove file" it gives me the last error described in the 4th code above.